# How to pre load ember engines?

Tags: ember.js, ember-engines

Am using [ember-engines](https://ember-engines.com/) in my project, After user lands in host ember application, I want my other ember engines to preload (say after 10 seconds), so that when user navigates to other tabs, there wont be any lag in UI.. i dont want to disable lazyLoading of my ember engines since that will increase the size of vendor js and css of host app during initial load.. Any reference for this is appreciated (I was not able to find any example or reference for this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `loadBundle` method of `asset-loader` service included by `ember-engine` as follow:

```js
assetLoader: service(),

preloadEngine() {
  this.assetLoader.loadBundle('<name of the engine>');
}
```

The `loadBundle` method [return a promise](https://github.com/ember-engines/ember-asset-loader/blob/master/addon/services/asset-loader.js#L71-L76) and resolves when the engine bundle loads successfully.

Comment: Followed the same in host application route.js.. getting this.assetLoader.loadBundle is not a function error...
in node-modules folder of host app, there is ember-asset-loader folder too..
Am i missing anything?

Comment: just replaced below statement:
this.assetLoader.loadBundle(name)

with
this.get('assetLoader').loadBundle(name)

and it worked... thank you...